# CSS/Javascript to align a word on a specific character

Tags: javascript, html, css

How could I use CSS/Javascript to align a word in html by an arbitrary character in that word, changing the styling of the aligned character (ex. make it bold) to contrast with the other characters, like in this example, aligning and bolding 'k', 'e', 't', and 'f':

```
-stack
---overflow
----stack
-overflow
```

edit: Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this in non monospaced fonts.

Comment: One probable way to do this is find out all those characters with javascript and replace like 'k' with '<span class="mystyle">k</span>' and now apply your style on class mystyle.

Comment: and i have to add that it can only be precisely done using monospaced fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a two-column table, where each row contains one line of the text and the second cell starts with the desired character, which is wrapped in a text-level container. Then you just style that container and right-align the first column. Example:

```
<style>
.aw { border-collapse: collapse; } /* remove cell spacing */
.aw td { padding: 0; }             /* remove cell padding */
.aw td:first-child { text-align: right; }
.aw b { font-weight: bold; color: red; }
</style>
<table class=aw>
<tr><td>stac<td><b>k</b>
<tr><td>ov<td><b>e</b>rflow
<tr><td>s<td><b>t</b>ack
<tr><td>over<td><b>f</b>low
</table>
```

You can dispense with the text-level containers ('b' elements in the example) if you use the `:first-letter` pseudo-element. But that pseudo-element does not work consistently if the first character in the element is not literally a letter but e.g. a punctuation mark or a digit.