# Make specific character (or class/ID) be the center point of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to align some text in the center, but not just by doing `text-align: center`.

I would like to make a specific character/class/ID be the center, while the rest of the string gets appended and prepended nicely. Here is what I mean:

https://jsfiddle.net/6w5Lb6ta/

[image]

As you can see, the red `c` in the middle is aligned somewhat in the middle (I used `margin-right` to make this small example). I want to say something like:

> align all the text in the middle, but make the 'anchor point' of the string a specific character/class/ID

Is something like this doable?

Comment: This maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140156/css-javascript-to-align-a-word-on-a-specific-character . Maybe not.

Comment: @Turnip I don't think so. Thanks, though!

Comment: @Snorlax Are you looking for one line string or text can be wrapped?

Comment: @VisioN One line. Atticweb already made a good solution for me.

Comment: @Snorlax Good enough? How about a [no-JS one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37881927/1249581)?

Comment: @Paulie_D It can be done with CSS. Check the answer below.

Comment: @Paulie_D How is it not real?

Comment: @Paulie_D Works fine though, so what's the problem?

Comment: I just commented..I didn't downvote..although I might now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with some jQuery:

```
var width = $('#text').width()/2;
var width2 = $('#center').width()/2;
var left = $('#center').offset().left;
$('#text').css('margin-right', (left-width+width2)*2);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6w5Lb6ta/7/

Comment: I suppose that's one way to do it. Pretty? Nope. But it's alright haha. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work. Try moving the `<span id="center">c</span>` to somewhere else, like the beginning of the string or the end of it. Or simply write more text inside the span-tag.

Comment: So far so good! However, the text is being aligned in the middle according to the character's "left". If the character is `M` the text will be aligned on the M's left and not the M's middle. So I suppose we need to grab the width of the character, right?

Answer (score 0):

How about some CSS hacking? `;)`

I used `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements, you can replace them with standard elements to make text selectable.

```css
div {
  font-size: 2em;
  display: table;
  color: #f00;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div:before, div:after {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  color: initial;
}

div:before {
  content: attr(data-before);
  text-align: right;
}

div:after {
  content: attr(data-after);
}
```

```html
<div data-before="Here is some text. Align&nbsp;" data-after="enter on the red c">c</div>
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/6w5Lb6ta/8/

Comment: Works as well, however, I'd rather not use those attributes to put in my text, since I'm using Javascript to do this anyway ;) Thanks though!

Comment: @Snorlax Don't forget that JavaScript solution will break with page resizing: you have to maintain the same output for different screen sizes and resolutions. This should always work.

Comment: Not with the thing I'm doing, as I am updating text pretty fast. So it's calculating the new width anyway :)

Comment: @Snorlax Up to you. Here is a solution with standard elements: https://jsfiddle.net/6w5Lb6ta/10/.

Comment: @Snorlax Yeah, and much faster and smooth than any JS `;D`

Comment: Too bad it's Sass CSS :(

Comment: @Snorlax Oh, it's easy to transform it back to ordinary CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/6w5Lb6ta/11/.

Comment: Consider it done! Thanks haha. Better to do it this way I agree ;)